# "The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred." Is an error I keep getting on discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I've just completed writing a ping.js, echo.js, guildMemberAdd.js, and guildMemberRemove.js and I'm moving on to writing a ban.js and kick.js and currently all slash commands work except the latest commands which is kick and ban. I keep getting the error that "The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred." and I have no idea how to find a solution to it. I originally had it written "return interaction.followUp" and I switched them all to "await interaction.followUp" hoping it'd be the solution the problem, but it seems like that wasn't it. I originally also had it written "run: async (interaction) => {" but then I get the error that "command.execute" is not a function so I switched it to "async execute (intereaction) {" I've also tried a couple of other things, but still can't seem to find a fix, does anyone have any idea on this? I'll leave my interactionCreate.js and kick.js below

interactionCreate.js

```
    module.exports = {
        name: "interactionCreate",
        async execute(interaction) {
            if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    
            const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    
            if (!command) return;
    
            try {
                await command.execute(interaction);
            } catch (err) {
                if (err) console.error(err);
    
                await interaction.reply({
                    content: "An error occured while executing that command.",
                    ephemeral: true
                });
            }
    
        }
    }
```

kick.js

```
    const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
    const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
    
    module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("kick")
        .setDescription("Allows the admin or owner to kick the member.")
        .addUserOption((option) => option.setName('user').setDescription('The person who you want to kick').setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('reason').setDescription('Reason to kick member').setRequired(true)),
        async execute (interaction) {
    
           if(!interaction.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return interaction.followUp({ content: "You do not have the power to kick that member.", ephemeral: true })
    
            const user = interaction.options.getUser('user')
            const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id) || await interaction.guild.members.fetch(user.id).catch(err => {})
    
            if(!member) return interaction.followUp({ content: " | Well this is awkward... I'm unable to get details related to given member.", ephemeral: true });
            const reason = interaction.options.getString('reason')
    
            if(!member.kickable || member.user.id === member.user.id) 
            await interaction.followUp({ content: " | I am unable to kick this member", ephemeral: true });
            
            if(interaction.member.roles.highest.position <= member.roles.highest.position) 
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'This member has equal or higher power as you so I cannot kick them.', ephemeral: true })
            
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`**${member.user.tag}** is kicked out from the cookout for \`${reason}\``)
            .setColor("#5104DB")
            .setFooter({ text: "Kick Member" })
            .setTimestamp()
    
            await interaction.reply(`You are kicked from **\`${interaction.guild.name}\`** for \`${reason}\``).catch(err => {})
            member.kick();
    
            await interaction.followUp({ embeds: [ embed ]})
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: can't see your comment?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from line 19 and 22

```js
await interaction.followUp({ content: " | I am unable to kick this member", ephemeral: true });
```

```js
await interaction.followUp({ content: 'This member has equal or higher power as you so I cannot kick them.', ephemeral: true })
```

You attempt to `followUp` to an interaction, with no reply as the error message suggests. You can change this to `reply` as you do further down in the code, which will work.

*Note: you will likely receive unexpected errors if you don't `return` or stop the code when the conditions above are met*

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to await the `deferReply()` method first then do what I want to do, and then did a `followUp()` at the end when my time-consuming operations are done. This solved it for me.

```js
function(interaction) {
  await interaction.deferReply(); <-- make sure to await
  // Do other async or time-consuming operations
  // and when done:
  interaction.followUp(`Finished, here's the result: ${someResult}`)
}
```